# Verify that Function is Homomorphism for $\mathbb{Z}_8 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prof. Pinter's "A Book of Abstract Algebra" presents the following exercise:

> Consider the function $f: \mathbb{Z}_8 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_4$ given by:
>
> $f = (0 \rightarrow 0, 1 \rightarrow 1, 2 \rightarrow 2, 3 \rightarrow 3, 4 \rightarrow 0, 5 \rightarrow 1, 6 \rightarrow 2, 7 \rightarrow 3)$
>
> Verify that $f$ is a homomorphism.

At the beginning of this chapter, Prof. Pinter states:

> Definition: If $G$ and $H$ are groups, a **homomorphism** from $G$ to $H$ is a function: $f: G \rightarrow H$ such that for any two elements $a$ and $b$ in $G$, $$f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$$

It's not clear to me what operation $f$ represents. I thought that it was `modulo addition`, but I'm not sure what $f(a, b)$ represents (where $a$ and $b$ are elements of $G$, i.e. $\mathbb{Z}_8$). What about $f(a)f(b)$?

Please help me start the verification that $f$ is a homomorphism.

Comment: A better way of writing the homomorphism property to avoid some confusion might be: $f(a\circ b)=f(a)\star f(b)$, where $\circ$ is the binary operation in the first group and $\star$ is the binary operation in the second group. In the case in the problem you describe, $\circ$ is addition modulo $8$, and $\star$ is addition modulo $4$.

Comment: Then you want to check something along the lines of: $f(2+3 (\mod 8))=f(2)+f(3)(\mod 4)$? Hint: What function is the $f$ above describing? Can you think of a way of writing it in a closed form?

Answer (score 1):

To show that this $f$ is a homomorphism you have to check the property

$$ f(a+b) = f(a) + f(b)$$

for all $a,b \in \mathbb Z_8$. So here goes:

$$1 = f(1) = f(0 + 1) \text{ and  } f(0) + f(1) = 1$$

$$ 3 = f(3) = f(1+2) \text{ and } f(1) + f(2) = 3$$

and so on. But you don't need to check it for all combinations of all elements: It is enough to check it for all pairs $a,b$ where $a,b$ are [generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_group#Integer_and_modular_addition) of the group $\mathbb Z_8$. This will safe you some work.

The remaining cases are $(a,b) \in \{ (1,3), (1,5), (1,7), (3,5), (3,7), (5,7) \}$.

As has been pointed out in the other answer you also have to check that $f$ is well defined.

Answer (score 1):

We  have $f(x) = represent(x) (mod $ $ 4)$  $\forall x \in \mathbb{Z}_8$,
where $represent(x)$ is any integer from equivalence class $x$.

$f$ is a homomorphism of groups(with respect of addition). To prove that just check the definition

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure what $f(a, b)$ represents (where $a$ and $b$ are elements of $G$, i.e. $\mathbb{Z}_8$).

You're looking for $f(a+b)$, not $f(a,b)$. When $a+b$ are inside $f$, you first add (or perform the group's operation on) them and then find the image of their sum (or product).

For example, $f(2+ 3) = f(5)=1 \in \Bbb Z_4$.

Then $f(2)+f(3)=2 + 3= 5$, which equals $1$ in $\Bbb Z_4$, so $f(2 + 3)=f(2)+f(3)$.

(To show that it is a homomorphism, in additive notation, you have to show that $f(a+b) = f(a)+f(b)$ for all $a,b \in \Bbb Z_8$.)

Since the elements of $\Bbb Z_8$ are equivalence classes, you'll probably have to show that $f$ is well-defined too. (Here's where the fact that $4$ divides $8$ comes into play.)