# Find the Kernel of the Homomorphic $f:\mathbb{Z}_8 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Previously I posted a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1401041/verify-that-function-is-homomorphism-for-mathbbz-8-rightarrow-mathbbz-4) from "A Book of Abstract Algebra" to prove that the function, $f:\mathbb{Z}_8 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_4$ (shown below), is a homomorphism.

> $f = (0 \rightarrow 0, 1 \rightarrow 1, 2 \rightarrow 2, 3 \rightarrow 3, 
> 4 \rightarrow 0, 5 \rightarrow 1, 6 \rightarrow 2, 7 \rightarrow 3)$

This exercise also asks to find its **kernel**.

Quoting from the text:

> Given the groups $G$ and $H$, let $f: G \rightarrow H$ be a homomorphism. The **kernel** of $f$ is the set $K$ of all the elements of $G$ which are carried by $f$ onto the neutral element of $H$. That is, $$K = \lbrace x \in G : f(x) = e \rbrace$$

In $\mathbb{Z}_4$, 0 is the empty element since, per the identity element:

$e1 + e2 = e1$ where $e2$ is the identity element.

**Attempted Proof**

For $\mathbb{Z}_4$, the $f$ function in $f(x) = e$ means:

$$f(x) = 0$$
$$x \mod 4 = 0$$

Therefore, K = $\lbrace 0, 4 \rbrace$.

Please review my proof for correctness.

Comment: Looks correct. That is indeed the kernel.

Comment: Technically speaking, these are elements of $\mathbb{Z}_8$, so depending on your book the names $0$ and $4$  may not be the correct ones.

Comment: could you say more, Andre? I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Your question only asks for review on finding $\ker f$ so I will assume you already proved it to be homomorphic.

Since $f$ is explicitly defined for each element of the domain you might as well enumerate the elements that map to $0$, that are, as you found, $\{ 0, 4\}$. However, a more strictly formal way to iterate your proof would be to consider that your $f$ is defined in such a way that $f(x)=y \iff x \equiv _4 y$ ($\equiv _4$ being congruence modulo $4$), so, being $\equiv _4$ an equivalence relation, the $\ker f$ is also given by $[0]_{\equiv _4}$ (the equivalence class represented by $0$ with respect to $\equiv _4$) in $\mathbb Z _8$, which is indeed $\{0,4\}$.

So were I to edit your proof I would just add an extra step like this:
$K = [0]_{\equiv _4} = \{0,4\}$.